# SQLite nationalized string indicator

Tags: sql-server, sqlite

The following SQL statement does work with MSSQL but not with SQLite:

```
... where Table.Column = N'999';
```

It seems like nationalized indicators aren't supported in SQLite. Since I try to use MSSQL and SQLite at the same time with the same code base, it would be great to create a universal solution. Is there any syntax difference or configuration I am missing?

Comment: To rephrase your question and give you a better search term suggestion, you want to know how to search a column using a unicode string literal (not "nationalized indicator") in sqlite. And perhaps you only complicate things by using a string literal here if your column is a numeric datatype?

Comment: The number was an example. The constraint is arbitrary.

Answer (score 2):

In SQLite, all strings always are unicode strings, so a separate NVARCHAR type is not needed.

If you want to use the same syntax in both databases, you have to use an SQL Server codepage that contains all the characters you need.
(But it's likely that you will run into more differences.)